# JavaScript Alphanumeric Regex and allow asterisk at the start of the string but do not allow asterisk at the last 4 digits of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex ^[a-zA-Z0-9*]+$ for only allowing alphanumeric chars and allow Asterisk(*). But I would like allow asterisk only at the start of the string. But asterisk is not allowed at the last 4 digits of the string.

1. new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9*]+$').test('test') ---Valid
2. new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9*]+$').test('test1234') --Valid
3. new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9*]+$').test('test@#_')--Invalid
4. new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9*]+$').test('****1234') --Valid
5. new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9*]+$').test('*tes**1234') --Valid
6. new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9*]+$').test('test****') --**Should be Invalid**

"How would I  allow Asterisk only at the start of the string?" But if the asterisk presents in any of the last 4 positions then it should be invalid

Comment: Your question is ambiguous regarding asterisks between the first and the last four positions. The examples don't make that clear either. What about `*1*2345`, for example?

Comment: Yes, it is valid. Asterisk is allowed except for last 4 digits. And I have update that case with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to allow only alphanumeric chars and asterisk, but no asterisk at the last 4 char positions:

```js
const regex = /^(?:[a-z\d*]*[a-z\d]{4}|[a-z\d]{1,3})$/i;
[
  '1',
  '12',
  'test',
  'test1234',
  '****1234',
  '*tes**1234',
  '*1*2345',
  'test@#_',
  'test****',
  'test***5',
  'test**4*',
  '*3**'
].forEach(str => {
  let result = regex.test(str);
  console.log(str, '==>', result);
});
```

Output:

```
1 ==> true
12 ==> true
test ==> true
test1234 ==> true
****1234 ==> true
*tes**1234 ==> true
*1*2345 ==> true
test@#_ ==> false
test**** ==> false
test***5 ==> false
test**4* ==> false
*3** ==> false
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` -- anchor at start of string
- `(?:` -- start non-capture group (for logical OR)

  - `[a-z\d*]*[a-z\d]{4}` -- allow alphanumeric chars and asterisk, followed by 4 alphanumeric chars
- `|` -- logical OR

  - `[a-z\d]{1,3}` -- allow 1 to 3 alphanumeric chars
- `)` -- close group
- `$` -- anchor at end of string

Not that it is easier to read and more efficient to use `/.../` instead of `new RegExp("...")`. You need the regex constructor only if you have variable input.

Comment: Thanks. In my case this worked for me. That was a clear and concise explanation. Upvoting this since it passed all my test scenarios